# Excel 2016 new sheets show no gridlines?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2016

I'm not sure why, but a couple of days ago my Excel 2016 started acting up... Every time I add new sheets to a workbook, the new sheets have the "Show Gridlines" option OFF by default. It also happens when I create a blank workbook.

Do you know how to fix this?

Thanks

Comment: You can go to VIEW tab and check "Show Gridlines"

Comment: I am suggesting a workaround and assuming that you are using Windows 7 or above. Try and see if this helps. Open a blank workbook, click Show Gridlines. Now gridlines will be visible. Now save this as Excel template (Select Excel template in save as dialog box) named Book.xltx & Sheet.xltx at C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office15\XLSTART & also at C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Excel\XLSTART. This could be hidden folder. In Excel app File Options--> General --> Startup Options uncheck 'Show Start screen when application starts.

Answer (score 1):

This is very late, but for someone running into this issue in future I tried lots of different things to fix this without luck.

Eventually after an exhaustive search of the registry I found that deleting the `HKEY_USERS\<Your SID>\Software\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Excel\Options` key fixed it for Office 365 (v2008).

As always with the registry, back up the key first. You may lose any changes you've made to Excel options, but otherwise I haven't noticed any negative side effects.

Comment: I am sorry if this breaks SE rules, but I just want to say Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I can confirm that [mbza's solution](https://superuser.com/a/1683652/1744184) also works for Excel 2016.

Also, if you do not want to reset all of your settings, it seems to specifically be the `Options3` key.

I'm not sure what the key value should be to display grid lines but my key value was set to 0x00004040 (16448). After deleting this key my grid lines are back and no replacement key seems to have been made.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).